# Maven JAR Plugin 3.0.2 Error: You have to use a classifier to attach supplemental artifacts to the project instead of replacing them

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

Maven JAR plugin (version 3.0.2) keeps throwing the following error, **even for a single invocation of the `jar` goal**:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default) on project test: You have to use a classifier to attach supplemental artifacts to the project instead of replacing them. -> [Help 1]

Here's a (minimal?) `pom.xml` which demonstrates the problem:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The invocation is just `mvn package`.

- It doesn't seem to matter whether there are any classes/resources at all — the above error message appears anyway.
- The problem also appears if two goals are specified (`jar` and `test-jar`).
- The problem does NOT appear if **no goals** are specified. But this is not an option, since I really need both `jar` and `test-jar`.

According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier), `classifier` only needs to be specified on multiple invocations of the same goal, and there's a reasonable default for the `test-jar` goal which I don't intend to change.

Also, **the problem doesn't seem to appear on the 2.x line of the JAR plugin.**

Did I miss something? 
Could anybody please suggest what I am doing wrong?

P.S. The Maven version is 3.3.9.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The Jar Plugin is actually getting executed twice with the configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you check the logs with such a configuration, you will have something like:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ test ---
[INFO] Building jar: ...\test\target\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default) @ test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

meaning that the plugin was in fact executed twice. What happens, is that the Jar Plugin, in a project that has a packaging of `jar` [has a default execution bound to the `package` phase](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging). This default execution is the one mentioned in the logs with the ID of `default-jar`.

When you configured an `<execution>` in the plugin, you actually configured a new execution, where the `jar` goal of the plugin is to be invoked. Since the [`jar` goal binds by default to the `package` phase](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html), that execution is getting executed at that phase, after the default binding inherent to the `jar` packaging. And since the plugin ran already, it is failing because running it again would actually replace the main artifact already produced during the first run. This error was added in version 3.0.0 of the plugin in [MJAR-198](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-198), because such a thing happening is very likely a mis-configuration which should be detected early.

As such, the fix is simple: don't have an execution that specifies the goal `jar`, and let the default one (coming from the `jar` packaging) do the work. The JAR will still be created, even without the explicit configuration of the `jar` goal, thanks to the default execution. If you want a test JAR as well, [you will still need to configure the plugin to do that](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) with:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But note that the goal `jar` is not specified.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I faced the problem even though I've set packaging to "war" (and not "jar"), but removing the <phase>package</phase> inside the jar-plugin fixed the problem.

Comment: I get this error only in a multi module  setup only in an environment using jenkins and linux. On a Mac OS machine things run and they also in the Travis CI environment. There seems to be more trickery going on which is frustrating. IMHO the error message is more confusing then helping and it only points to this stackoverflow article.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I have set the execution ID to `default-jar`, overriding the default execution. Then the error is gone.

```
<execution>
    <id>default-jar</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Comment: That "works" but is based on the fact that having `default-jar` as the execution ID overrides the default execution from the `jar` packaging. This is a bit of a hack, and there is a better solution.

Comment: This is not necessarily a hack. Imagine you want to run the default `jar` goal, but with a custom configuration. In that case, matching the ID `default-jar` becomes a legitimate use case:

`
<execution>
    <id>default-jar</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
    </configuration>
</execution>
`

Answer (score 10):

If your logs shows something like:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ test --
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
```

Adding a single useless class in src/main/java seems to solve the issue see:

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/quot-mvn-clean-verify-deploy-quot-causes-jar-plugin-to-execute-twice-td5877166.html

Since the above link might be broken as of 2021-09 you might want to try http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201608.mbox/thread as an alternative

Comment: Thanks for the link! There is also mentioned the case of calling mvn clean verify deploy, which does everything until verify twice. In my case a mvn clean install deploy broke, but mvn clean deploy worked. (Had an empty JAR, too.)

Comment: The link seems broken

Comment: @Sniper - thx i tried finding an alternative source for the mailing list archive

Answer (score 4):

I got the error

> Maven JAR Plugin 3.0.2 Error: You have to use a classifier to attach
> supplemental artifacts to the project instead of replacing them

when I was building a WAR but needed an extra JAR file to resolve external dependencies in another project.

I solved the problem simply by adding a configuration element containing a "classifier". This simply means the JAR file will have the classifier as a suffix in its name.

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <classifier>identify_your_jar_file_differently</classifier>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Looks like the real answer that is not a hack or a workaround. You did what the message told you to do. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One reason to have this error may be that the `package` goal is mistakenly executed twice:

```
mvn ... package ... package
```

May happen when the command is built by imperfect scripts :)

Answer (score 1):

A little late but you should add `<phase>none</phase>` to default-jar execution. this will skip it.

```
<execution>
  <id>default-jar</id>
  <phase>none</phase>
</execution>
```

This will skip the default-jar but others are executed. Make sure you put `<phase>package</phase>`  in the rest of the execution threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `maven-assembly-plugin` and when I upgraded from Maven 3.6.3 to Maven 3.9.6 I started getting this error, even though I never added the `maven-jar-plugin`. The solution was to add it as disabled like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>unwanted</finalName>
                <classifier>unwanted</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```