# Properly implementing Java modules in a Maven build with inter-module test dependencies

Tags: java, maven, junit, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I have a multi-module project using Maven and Java. I am now trying to migrate to Java 9/10/11 and implement modules (as in [JSR 376: Java Platform Module System](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=376), JPMS). As the project was already consisting of Maven modules, and the dependencies were straight, creating module descriptors for the project was quite straight forward.

Each Maven module now has their own module descriptor (`module-info.java`), in the `src/main/java` folder. There is no module descriptor for the test classes.

However, I stumbled upon a problem I have not been able to solve, and not found any descriptions on how to solve:

**How can I have inter-module *test* dependencies with Maven and Java modules?**

In my case, I have a "common" Maven module, which contains some interfaces and/or abstract classes (but no concrete implementation). In the same Maven module, I have *abstract* tests to ensure proper behavior for the implementation of these interfaces/abstract classes. Then, there are one or more sub modules, with implementations of the interface/abstract class and tests extending the abstract test.

However, when trying to execute the `test` phase of the Maven build, the sub module will fail with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project my-impl-module: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\projects\com.example\my-module-test\my-impl-module\src\test\java\com\example\impl\FooImplTest.java:[4,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FooAbstractTest
[ERROR]   location: package com.example.common
```

I suspect that this happens because the *tests are not part of the module*. And even if Maven does some "magic" to get the tests executed within the scope of the module, it doesn't work for the tests in the module I depend on (for some reason). How do I fix this?

The structure of the project looks like this ([full demo project files available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmu9xdd8mlytpfb/my-module-test.zip?dl=0)):

```
├───my-common-module
│   ├───pom.xml
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   └───java
│       │       ├───com
│       │       │   └───example
│       │       │       └───common
│       │       │           ├───AbstractFoo.java (abstract, implements Foo)
│       │       │           └───Foo.java (interface)
│       │       └───module-info.java (my.common.module: exports com.example.common)
│       └───test
│           └───java
│               └───com
│                   └───example
│                       └───common
│                           └───FooAbstractTest.java (abstract class, tests Foo)
├───my-impl-module
│   ├───pom.xml
│   └───src
│       ├───main
│       │   └───java
│       │       ├───com
│       │       │   └───example
│       │       │       └───impl
│       │       │           └───FooImpl.java (extends AbstractFoo)
│       │       └───module-info.java (my.impl.module: requires my.common.module)
│       └───test
│           └───java
│               └───com
│                   └───example
│                       └───impl
│                           └───FooImplTest.java (extends FooAbstractTest)
└───pom.xml
```

Dependencies in the `my-impl-module/pom.xml` is as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-common-module</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-common-module</artifactId>
        <classifier>tests</classifier> <!-- tried type:test-jar instead, same error -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note: The above is just a project I created to demonstrate the problem. The real project is a lot more complex, and [found here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) (master branch is *not* modularized yet), but the principle is the same.

PS: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code itself, as everything compiles and runs using normal class path (ie. in IntelliJ, or Maven without the Java module descriptors). The problem is introduced with Java modules and the module path.

Comment: No doubts such questions would arise and a good read for them would be  [this answer by Sormuras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110023/how-do-you-organize-tests-in-a-modular-java-project/52110406#52110406) which links to various useful links as well that can help you categorise your tests while working on modular projects.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/174670/947199) work for you? Summarising, add the goal test-jar to your  `my-common-module` and then change <classifier>tests</classifier> per <type>test-jar</type> in the `my-impl-module/pom.xml` my-common-module dependency. I've tried and it works well.

Comment: @troig Thanks. Did you try it with JPMS modules? I get the exact same problem using `test-jar` dependency.

Comment: @haraldK ,I only tried it with a multi-module maven project, but not JPMS. Sorry about that. I'll be waiing for other answers, good question!

Comment: @nullpointer Interesting read, but I didn't really find a solution to my problem there... Do you have any suggestions? I'm doing white box testing, obviously.

Comment: @haraldK Possibly related, maybe trying this could help [Java9 Multi-Module Maven Project Test Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146491/java9-multi-module-maven-project-test-dependencies)..
No more suggestions actually on this front. Constrained by two things - *Time* to not give it an actual handson && *Migration* effectively at a place where I am investing major time currently. :|

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on your demo project, I was able to duplicate your error.  That said, here are the **revised** changes I made, after my first failed attempt, to be able to build the project:

1. I added the `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.8.0 to all the modules.  You need a version of 3.7 or higher to compile modules with Maven - at least that's the warning NetBeans showed.  Since there is no harm, I added the pluging to both the *common* and *implementation* modules' POM files:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>compile</goal>
               </goals>
               <id>compile</id>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. I exported the test classes into their own `jar` file so they will be available to your implementation module or anyone for that matter.  To do that, you need to add the following to your `my-common-module/pom.xml` file:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>test-jar</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>test-jar</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   This will export `my-common-module` test classes into `-tests.jar` file - i.e.`my-common-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar`.  Notice there is no need to add an execution for the regular `jar` file as noted in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964500/maven-jar-plugin-3-0-2-error-you-have-to-use-a-classifier-to-attach-supplementa/40964626#40964626).  This will, however, introduced error that I will address next.
3. Rename your test package in `my-common-module` to `com.example.common.test` in order for the test classes to be loaded when compiling the implementation test class(es).  This corrects the class load issue introduced when we exported the test classes with the same package name as in the module where the first `jar`, in this case the module, is loaded and the second `jar`, the test jar file, is ignored. Interesting enough, I'm concluding, based on observation, that the module path has higher precedence than the class path since the Maven compile parameters shows the `tests.jar` is specified first in the class path.  Running `mvn clean validate test -X`, we see compile parameters:

   ```
   -d /home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/target/test-classes -classpath /home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/target/test-classes:/home/testenv/.m2/repository/com/example/Declaration/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Declaration-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar:/home/testenv/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/home/testenv/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar: --module-path /home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/target/classes:/home/testenv/.m2/repository/com/example/Declaration/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Declaration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: -sourcepath /home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/src/test/java:/home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations: -s /home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations -g -nowarn -target 11 -source 11 -encoding UTF-8 --patch-module example.implementation=/home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/target/classes:/home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/src/test/java:/home/testenv/NetBeansProjects/MavenProject/Implementation/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations: --add-reads example.implementation=ALL-UNNAMED
   ```
4. We need to make the exported test classes available to the implementation module.  Add this dependency to your `my-impl-module/pom.xml`:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>Declaration</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <type>test-jar</type>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
5. Lastly in the `my-impl-module` test class, update the import to specify the new test package, `com.example.common.text`, to access the `my-common-module` test classes:

   ```
   import com.example.declaration.test.AbstractFooTest;
   import com.example.declaration.Foo;
   import org.junit.Test;
   import static org.junit.Assert.*;

   /**
    * Test class inheriting from common module...
    */
   public class FooImplementationTest extends AbstractFooTest { ... }
   ```

Here is the test results from my `mvn clean package` of the new changes:

[image]

I updated my sample code in my [java-cross-module-testing](https://github.com/jhenriquez418/java-cross-module-testing) GitHub repo.  The only lingering question I have, and I'm sure you do as well, is why did it worked when I defined the implementation module as a regular `jar` project instead of a module.  But that, I'll play with some other day.  Hopefully what I provided solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks to give this a try, but it seems this doesn't solve not the exact problem haraldK described. It doesn't fully use JPMS: Your example project doesn't have a `module-info.java` for "Implementation". When I add an appropriate `Implementation/src/main/java/module-info.java`, it fails with: "module not found: com.example.declaration"

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned in the comments and `pom.xml` extract, I have already tried the `test-jar` approach. It works fine without JPMS modules. But it gives exactly the same error when you add them, unfortunately. What makes your project work is the fact that *you don't have* a `module-info.java` in your "Implementation" module, as @CoderNr23 points out. That is not a solution, sorry.

Comment: I appreciate the effort! The updated answer does make the test project build, but it completely sidesteps the problem. Unfortunately, I can't change the package name of the tests as you do in step 3. In the real project I refer to, I have package scoped classes that implements `Foo` (ie. `DefaultFoo`) here that I need to test. This also means that introducing a separate module for the abstract tests only, will not work (would cause circular dependency, or require duplicated test code).

Comment: Then the only other solution that comes to mind is including all `my-common-module` class files into the `tests.jar`.  Obviously, you will need to exclude the module dependency when running test.  See if the [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) helps.

Comment: The [Maven Jar Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) documentation suggests creating a separate test project.  This may also be another possible avenue for you.

Comment: I just don't get it... I've downloaded your project, and it somehow works. I made all the same changes to my own project (only difference now, is names of modules and packages). And guess what? It *still won't compile!* Same error as above. I do believe your answer is correct though. I just need to understand why...

Comment: I'll give you the check for now, so you'll get the bounty. :-) I might self-answer or provide an edit for your answer though, as it doesn't fully explain why my project didn't work.

Comment: Okay.. After scratching my head for some time, it seems that the problem was the *name of the module* in the `module-info.java`... :-( If the common module is named `my.common.module` (same as Maven module `my-common-module`, with dots instead of hyphens) it fails with a compilation error (`-X` shows the `*-test.jar` isn't even on the class path in this case). If the module name is `common.module` (or pretty much anything but the above), all is good. Is this a Maven bug?

Comment: @haraldK, I named the modules using dots instead of hyphens in order to be consistent with the Java module naming convention - execute `java --list-modules` to see the defined JDK modules names.  As far as your project, just make sure you're consistent with your modules names, specially in your `requires` statements.  For example if you named your declaration module `example.declaration`, you must specify `example.declaration` in your implementation `module-info.java`->`requires` statement.  See my sample code for reference.

Comment: @haraldk, lastly... your Maven project name does not define your module name.  The module name is in defined in the project's `module-info.java`.

Comment: Ok, so in conclusion: you can only get a test-jar dependency to work if the tests are in seperate packages. For a case with complex "white box testing", that will not be a good solution. But for most other cases (including mine), that's probably an acceptable workaround.

Comment: By the way, I've also been digging a little deeper into this. _As far as I understand_, the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) compiles and runs the tests. It needs to do a lot of tinkering to get this working with JPMS. In this case, to get it to work, it would have to merge `main` and `test` classes in one jar. But that kinda breaks the entire logic behind a seperate main jar and "test-jar". So I guess there's no obvious way that surefire can get this working.

Comment: @JoseHenriquez You don't seem to understand what I'm saying (sorry if I was unclear). I know all that. What I'm saying is that your project *will not build, if the Maven `atifactId` and the JPMS `module` name is the same*! You can see the effect in your project if you rename your module to `Declaration` (case sensitive) *or* change your `artifactId` to `example-declaration`. Even though everything is correct and consistent.

Comment: @JoseHenriquez You can verify the above, by running `mvn clean package -X` and see that when the names are equal, the "declaration" test-jar is not placed on class path during the `testCompile` step for the "implementation" module, and it will fail with a compilation error.

Comment: @haraldK, you're right!  It's not adding the `-tests-jar` file when running tests.  I tried with a period and a hyphen with the same results.  My hunch is that Maven doesn't find the file because those "special" characters in the jar file name is breaking the parsing logic when looking for the string "-tests-jar".  I got the same error when I created a new project from scratch - just in case I messed up in renaming the Maven modules.  Definitely a Maven bug.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do exactly the same, it's not possible to have both whitebox tests and module test-dependencies **with your project structure**, but I think I found an alternative structure that does 90% of what you want to do:

1/ The problem with whitebox testing is that it works with module patching, because JPMS has not notion of test VS main unlike Maven. So this provokes problems like not working with test-dependencies, or having to pollute your module-info with test dependencies.

2/ So then, why not keep doing whitebox testing, but with the maven structure of  blackbox testing, that is: split each module X into X and X-test. 
Only X has a module-info.java, tests run in the classpath so you skip all these issues.

The only drawbacks I can think of are (in order of increasing importance):

1. That the test jar will not be modularized, but I think that is acceptable (at least for now).
2. That you have twice the number of maven modules, and you might not like separating tests in another maven module.
3. Tests will run in the classpath, and it's always bad to run tests in a different environment (the tests will run with less restrictions than the main code). This could maybe be mitigated by smoke tests or by a dedicated integration tests module? The "official patterns" have not emerged yet.

By the way (if that's what you're doing) I doubt it's worth it modularizing eg. a spring boot app as spring itself is not modularized yet, so you will pay the cost but reap few benefits (but if you're writing a lib that's a different story).

You can find an example here:

a/ Get the example:

git clone https://github.com/vandekeiser/ddd-metamodel.git

git checkout stackoverflow

b/ Look at the example:

1. fr.cla.ddd.metamodel depends on fr.cla.ddd.oo (but no module-info for the tests maven modules)
2. I do whitebox testing in PackagePrivateOoTest and in PackagePrivateMetamodelTest
3. I have a test-depency OoTestDependency