# JPro Maven build failing with UncheckedExecutionException

Tags: java, maven, javafx, pom.xml

I am trying to run a simple JavaFX [JPro](https://www.jpro.one/) demo project using Maven.

This is my file structure:

```
C:.
├───.idea
├───logs
├───src
│   └───main
│       └───java
│           └───com
│               └───example
└───target
    ├───classes
    │   └───com
    │       └───example
    ├───generated-sources
    │   └───annotations
    ├───jpro
    │   └───fonts
    └───maven-status
        └───maven-compiler-plugin
            └───compile
                ├───default-cli
                └───default-compile
```

My pom file contains this code, based on the sample located [here](https://www.jpro.one/?page=docs/current/1.1/Let%27s%20get%20started):

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JProDemoMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jpro.version>2020.1.5</jpro.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <name>Hello JPro!</name>
    <url>https://www.jpro.one/</url>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sandec.jpro</groupId>
                <artifactId>jpro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jpro.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <visible>false</visible>
                    <JVMArgs>
                        <!-- <JVMArg>your-args</JVMArg> -->
                    </JVMArgs>
                    <mainClassName>com.example.App</mainClassName>
                    <openingPath>/</openingPath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jpro - sandec repository</id>
            <url>https://sandec.bintray.com/repo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jpro - sandec repository</id>
            <url>https://sandec.bintray.com/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sandec.jpro</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpro-webapi</artifactId>
            <version>${jpro.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

The problem is, when I run the code using `mvn jpro:run`, I get the following length stacktrace:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:592)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor.initializeBinding(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:173)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor.lambda$scheduleInitialization$0(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:160)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:124)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:108)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:155)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:54)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:30)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at com.jpro.boot.JProBoot.callMain(JProBoot.java:92)
        at com.jpro.boot.JProBoot$1.run(JProBoot.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:30)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:43)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String
,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2271d8f4
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:149)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:23)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.
ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2271d8f4
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        ... 52 more
```

What causes this error? I suspect it has something to do with JavaFX, but I don't really know where to begin. How should I configure my project to get it to run?

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477690/properly-implementing-java-modules-in-a-maven-build-with-inter-module-test-depen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the version of [JPro](https://www.jpro.one/) you are using doesn't support Java16.

It works with the newly released version `2021.1.1`. (Which wasn't available when the question was asked)