# Maven Jar Plugin: How to add all files

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

I'm trying to use maven-jar-plugin to produce both a war file and a jar file doing `./mvnw clean install`.

My pom.xml contains:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-services-provided</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}\${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I also tried with `<phase>compile</phase>`.

The jar-file is being created but is very small and does not even contain the application main class.

How can I achieve the same result as `<packaging>jar</packaging>` ? The war-file looks good it is bigger.

I did read [Maven JAR Plugin 3.0.2 Error ..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964500/maven-jar-plugin-3-0-2-error-you-have-to-use-a-classifier-to-attach-supplementa).

Comment: Simply the wrong way. If you like to create a jar file use packaging jar and if your like to create a war file use packaging war instead. If you have a war project which should produce a war file and a jar file which contains the java code compiled use the configuration of maven-war-plugin ....

Answer (score -1):

If you like to create a separate jar file of the code in your war module the [configuration should look like this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```